# How to make modal dialog in rc5?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I tried a bunch of dialog modules but non of them work with rc5. Some of them create dialogs with components and service, some make this ugly solution with adding html in template. I prefer the first ones, **is there any that works ok**?

Also I thought about writing my own component with service but don't get in if angular have something to render elements otuside of components. In that case is there a good article?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @FriOne there is a lot of logic that goes in to creating a modal you can check out a library i'v been working on [here](https://github.com/flauc/ng2-simple-components).

It's not completely finished but you can install it with npm, and you should be able to use the `@ModalModule` with out any problems.

Just follow the documentation  [here](https://github.com/flauc/ng2-simple-components/blob/master/docs/modal.md).

Comment: Your library have wrong typings and can't ba used. Thanks anyway. It would be great if it has parameters when you create modal. I looked at ng2-modal component code and it was made with generics.

Comment: Yes it just has general typings. Like i said it's not finished, but what do you mean it can't be used? I use it all the times. When you say it has parameters when you create modal, what exactly do you mean? As it is now you can send any component what so ever and it dynamically creates it in the modal.

Comment: You can check out the example folder in the main branch or the ghpages branch to see a usage example.

Comment: I ment type errors.. about the params, how to provide data to a modal? For example if I need to show edit modal.

Comment: You would need to create a component that does that and then inject it in to the modal.

Comment: No, I mean a data, e.g. entity id. How to create a modal to edit entity with a form? Or maybe I just don't understand, please, give an example.

Comment: :) Ok, now I see, you edited the modal example in app.component.